# How can I show different category layout from three different modules?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

One of client of my projects has asked me to aggregate two different modules in one menu tab.
He needs like, if a user clicks on One Menu Tab, he needs a picture gallery and video gallery to be shown all together.
I have checked that it is possible by creating a category layout of each of them.But the thing is I cannot figure out how to show both of them together, under a single Menu Tab.
Please guide me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding you but can't you just publish both modules in the same module placeholder and assign them to the menu?

Comment: Sorry for that, But the thing is I need to show two or more components(Category Layout) in a single page or a single menu Tab.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm assuming there aren't appropriate modules for these components that you could use instead?